# Dash dynamic updating of AG Grid cells inside a callback

Tags: python, ag-grid, plotly-dash

I'm looking for some help in how to persist my original dataframe values in my Dash app while allowing users to dynamically modify the cell values in AG Grid either by manual cell edit, or using a slider to multiple all values in a column. a minimal example is provided below.

the issue I'm having is, when the user adjusts the slider, it overwrites the table values, which is expected, but every time they adjust the slider, the values just keep increasing.. what I need is to maintain the original values - even if the user manually types in a new value into the cell - the slider then operates on those new values.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
# make a copy of the origina column so the user can make edits:  called "Planner"
df['Planner'] = df['Predictions']

@app.callback(
    Output('pred_grid', 'rowData'),
    Output('pred_grid', 'columnDefs'),
    Input('slider_multiplier', 'value'),  # slider to allow the user to make adjustments on all values at once
    Input("pred_grid", "cellValueChanged"),
    State('pred_grid', 'rowData')
 )
 def make_grid(slider, cell_chng, row_cng):

button_id = ctx.triggered_id if not None else 'No clicks yet'
cols = [{"field": i} for i in df.columns]

# This condition works correctly.
if not cell_chng:
    planner_preds = df['Predictions'].values
    r = df.copy()

    if not button_id == 'slider_multiplier':
        r2 = df.to_dict('records')

    else:
        t = planner_preds
        mlt = np.repeat(slider, len(t))
        r['Planner'] = np.round(df['Predictions']*(1+mlt),0)
        r2 = r.to_dict("records")           

# This condition fails because if I manually edit he cell value, then try to move the 
  slider, the original values keep getting updated, so moving the slider keeps 
  increasing the values indefinitely.

# What I expect to happen is that when I edit the cells directly, the new values are 
  used as the base values for when the slider is then used for multiplication.  So, when 
  the user moves the slider up all the values are multiplied (i.e. 34*(1.05)), but when 
  the user moves the slider back down the same base values are used for that 
  calculation.  Instead what's happening is that the slider multiplies the values, then 
  updates the row data, which is then used to multiply new values... so, it's always 
  increasing.  I can't seem to figure out how to make this work as expected... 

else:
    # This part works
    if not button_id == 'slider_multiplier':
        r2 = pd.DataFrame(row_cng, columns=[i for i in df.columns])
        r2 = r2.to_dict("records")
    
    # This part does not work because row_cng is always updated in the callback; I need 
    to hold the original values, or manually edited values constant 
    else:
        r2 = pd.DataFrame(row_cng, columns=[i for i in df.columns])           
        t = [int(i) for i in r2['Planner']]
        mlt = np.repeat(slider, len(t))
        r2['Planner'] = np.round(t*(1+mlt),2)
        r2 = r2.to_dict("records")
 
 return r2, cols
```

The picture shows the idea.  I can manually edit those cell values by double click.  no problem.  but if I try to use the slider, it keeps the modified value, and that modified value becomes the new "base" value for the next time the slider is moved.  I want to keep the original base value when adjusting the slider (multiplier).  For example, I move the slider up to .5 in this example, the value 23 is multiple by 1.5, which becomes 34.5.  if I then move the slider again to say .2, then 34.5 is multiplied by 1.2... that's wrong, I want 23 to be multiplied by 1.2.  If I manually change 23 to 5, then I want the same logic to be applied to 5, not 23.
[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide!